# Is it true that ${1\over x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is it true that ${1\over x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots$?

It was used during a formal solution regarding big $O$ notation as if it were a fairly familiar identity, but there was nothing mentioned about area of definition and so. I myself have progressed relatively enough to have encountered that expansion at some point, I believe. Something in that equality seems somewhat confusing, and I can't seem to arrive at it using Taylor Expansions. It takes some ugly work to find a pattern of an expansion around a nonzero number.

Could you should shed some light on this please?

(I am sorry for all the tags: if I knew what area gives a simplified background to that identity, if true, I would tag it respectively.)

Comment: No. It's $\dfrac1{1+x}$, and it's valid for $\lvert x\rvert <1$. It results from a well-known high-school identity, the factorisation of $1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$.

Comment: Try $\frac 1{1+x}$ - if you multiply the right-hand side of your expression by $1+x$ you will see how things cancel. It may be valid in various contexts (e.g. formal power series).

Comment: I thought I was wrong assuming that. Spent way too much time on that. Thank you both

Comment: To expand on what Bernard said, the equality would hold if you replace all of the $x$'s on the right hand side with $(x-1)$.

Comment: Yes this is that exact substitution I have just made.

Comment: @Bernard Post your comment noting the essential typo as the answer. The other posted answers address  the literal question asked but not the one the OP needs an answer to.

Comment: Plug in 1 and see

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's  $\dfrac1{1+x}$, not $\dfrac1x$, and it's valid for $\lvert x\rvert<1$. This results from the following high-school identity
$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots x^{n-1}),$$
which can be re-written as $$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots x^{n-1}+\frac{x^n}{1-x}.$$
If $\lvert x\rvert<1$, $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, which proves 
$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dotsm$$
Setting $x\leftarrow -x$, you obtain
$$\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\dotsm$$

Comment: I like your $x \leftarrow -x$ approach ... simple and easy . :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|-x| < 1$, as the common ratio is $-x$ ?

Comment: @Nirbhay: $|x| = |-x|$, therefore $|x|<1\iff|-x|<1$

Comment: @celtschk Thats obviously ture .... thanks for telling ...... however the best way to write to avoid confusion is to write $|-x|$...isn't it?

Comment: @Nirbhay: No. I don't see what confusion would be avoided by writing $|-x|$ instead of $|x|$.

Comment: @celtschk Confusion = Confusion for beginners that common ration $r=|-x|$.....it is worthless to discuss over this topic....so I think we should end this discussion here only. :-)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** : Take $x=0$. Is the expression equal to $\dfrac {1}{0}$ ???

> It is essentially a geometric series with common ratio $r=-x$. For $|r| > 1$, the series diverges and thus the sum is **infinity** $\Bigg($ and NOT $\dfrac{1}{x}$ $\Bigg)$. The formula for sum of an infinite geometric series with $|r|<1 $ is $\dfrac{a}{1-r},$ where $a$ is the first term of the series. In this case, $a=1$, and $r=-x$. Therefore the infinite sum is $\dfrac{1}{1-(-x)} = \dfrac{1}{1+x}$. Therefore, concluding the answer, $$\\\boxed {\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^k = \dfrac{1}{1+x} \,\,\,\,\,\, for \,\,\,\,\,|-x|<1.}$$

Comment: Note that the capitalized word "not" has been used to emphasize and not as sth offensive. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take $x=-0.1$.

Then $$\frac1x=-10,$$

and

$$1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+\cdots=1.11111\cdots=\frac{10}9.$$

Comment: Downvote was not from me .... I appreciate your answer but I can not upvote as I have reached the daily vote limit.

Comment: @Nirbhay: your answer is much better !

Comment: Thanks a lot for the compliment. :-) I am just a newbie at answering..

Answer (score 2):

No, as others have pointed out, the real identity is

$$\dfrac 1{x+1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-\&\text c$$

You can prove this by synthetically dividing $1/(x+1)$ like below:

$$\begin{array}{c |c c} & 1 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & \cdots\\ -1 & & & -1 & & 1 & & -1 & & 1 & & -1 & & 1 & \cdots\\\hline & 1 & & -1 & & 1 & & -1 & & 1 & & -1 & & 1 & \cdots\end{array}\tag{1}$$
Where the top row, the $1,0,0,0,0\cdots$ is the numerator in terms of $x$, and the $-1$ is the negated denominator with the $x$ value omitted.

Therefore, it follows that$$\dfrac 1{x+1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+\&\text{c}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}(-1)^rx^r\tag{2}$$
However, note that this only converges if $|x|<1$.